# Autofocus when back using shift+tab

Tags: javascript, jquery, keypress, jquery-events

This is my form, if I am on PASSWORD field and want to go back to EMAIL field using <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>. How can I make it focus, I mean no need to click in EMAIL field to edit it?

This is my form logic:

1. the initial conditions for all fields are readonly / disabled, except the first field, user cannot go to next field and click next field
2. focus only on the fields that are being filled, other fields will be disabled / readonly.
3. if I fill in the email, the password and number fields are disabled,
4. When moving to the password field, email and number are disabled, you can return to the email field but cannot go to the number field if the password field is still empty

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Bootstrap Example</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<div class="container">
  <h2>Vertical (basic) form</h2>
  <form action="/action_page.php" method="post" name="subForm" id="subForm">
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="email">Email:</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" id="email" placeholder="Enter email" name="email">
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
      <label for="pwd">Password:</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" id="password" placeholder="Enter password" name="password">
    </div>
     <div class="form-group">
      <label for="pwd">Number:</label>
      <input type="number" class="form-control" id="number" placeholder="Enter Number" name="number">
    </div>

    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Submit</button>
  </form>
</div>
<script type="text/javascript">
function disableinputs(){
    $("#subForm input").prop('readonly', true);
}
$(document).ready(function(){
    disableinputs();
});
$(document).on('click','#subForm input',function(){
    $(this).prop('readonly', false);
});
$(document).on('focus','#subForm input',function(){
    $(this).prop('readonly', false);
});
$(document).on('focusout','#subForm input',function(){
    disableinputs();
});

</script>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("#email").focusout(function () {
        if (!$(this).val()) {
            $(this).focus();
        }
    });
    $("#password").focusout(function () {
        if (!$(this).val()) {
            $(this).focus();
            $("#email").focus();
        }
    });
    $("#number").focusout(function () {
        if (!$(this).val()) {
            $(this).focus();
            $("#number").focus();
        }
    });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```